# How to install az-cli on a locked up windows 10 without admin rights behind a company proxy?

Tags: azure, windows-10, command-line-interface, http-proxy

I was searching a long time to find out how to do this but everything I find ends up in some elevated shell situation. and I cannot configure the powershell proxy because of company restrictions.

Comment: Additionally to your answer, at my previous job I too had a restricted account on my own laptop. However, some commands that usually had to be run in an elevated shell (`npm install --global @angular/cli`) were actually able to execute, even from a non-elevated shell

Answer (score 3):

However, since I am doing this for 30 years, I seem to be much faster than most in choosing the right google answers. So here we go:

1. Download a current python install [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.1/python-3.11.1-amd64.exe)
2. run the installer with these settings:
3. [image: run the installer with these settings]
4. [image: these advanced options]
5. [image: there we go]
6. Open Powershell: `Win-R powershell`
7. The tricky bit is to find the extra install ( --use-pep517 and --proxy
   xxxxx options since the installer hangs otherwise: 
   `pip install --proxy http://YOURPROXY:PORT az-cli --use-pep517`
8. `Collecting az-cli Using cached az.cli-0.5-py3-none-any.whl (5.1 kB) Collecting azure-cli Using cached azure_cli-2.45.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.2 MB) Requirement already satisfied: antlr4-python3-runtime~=4.9.3 in c:\users\you\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from azure-cli->az-cli) (4.9.3) Collecting azure-appconfiguration~=1.1.1 ...........................`
   snip
9. next we configure the proxy for `az`:
10. `PS C:\Users\you>  $env:HTTP_PROXY='http://YOURPROXY:PORT'`  
    `PS C:\Users\you>  $env:HTTPS_PROXY='http://YOURPROXY:PORT'`
11. and we are ready to login to **azure**: `az login --tenant xxxxxx-xxxx-x-xx`
12. We also require `terraform` for our project from [here](https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/1.3.7/terraform_1.3.7_windows_amd64.zip)
13. Unpack: `PS C:\Users\you\Downloads> Expand-Archive .\terraform_1.3.7_windows_amd64.zip`
14. And copy it to the place you gonna need it, to save the hassle of setting up the PATH without admin rights:
    `cp .\terraform.exe ..\IdeaProjects\yourProject\terraform`
15. surprisingly i did not explicitly need to configure a proxy for terraform....
16. All Set!

Comment: Note this no longer seems to work in Python 3.12.0 (error message that you need C++ Build Tools installed, which also requires admin access). But it works great using the linked Python 3.11.1 version. So thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround solution that worked for me was to install [azure-cli with pip](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli/):

```bash
pip install azure-cli
```

Comment: This actually works. Just make sure, that if you are using a virtual environment in Python, you'll need to install it in the venv as well to work.